# How to get css information using rvest

Tags: r, rvest

I would like to retrieve the CSS for specific HTML elements using `rvest`.  For example, suppose I go to Google's homepage. If I inspect the webpage, and navigate to the 7th `input` element, I can see that it contains the `value = "Google Search"` attribute.  I can also see that using the code below.   However, I can't see the CSS applied to the element (font family, color, etc.) with `rvest`, but I can see it when inspecting the page.  How can I see the CSS using `rvest`?

```r
library(rvest)
library(tidyverse)

url <- r'(https://www.google.com)'

# get html element for 'Google Search' text
search_text <-
  read_html(url) %>% 
    html_elements('input') %>%
    pluck(7)

# print it
search_text
#> {html_node}
#> <input class="lsb" value="Google Search" name="btnG" type="submit">

# show all attributes
search_text %>% 
  html_attrs()
#>           class           value            name            type 
#>           "lsb" "Google Search"          "btnG"        "submit"
```

<sup>Created on 2023-12-12 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Unfortunately `rvest` isn't going to help you here. `rvest` can just read the raw HTML of the page. The values you seek are computed by your web browser when displaying the page. You need a full fledged CSS parser and rule applier to figure that stuff out and that's not a part of `rvest`. Instead you'll probably need to use a tool like `RSelenium` which allows you to remotely control a web browser and interact with the page that way. Though I'm not sure I've actually seen that used to inspected computed CSS properties but it might be worth a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The css for this class is stored in the body of the second `<style>` tag on the page. To extract it, we first get the name of the input's `class` attribute:

```r
library(rvest)
library(tidyverse)

url <- r'(https://www.google.com)'

css_class <- read_html(url) %>% 
  html_elements('input') %>%
  pluck(7) %>%
  html_attr('class')

css_class
#> [1] "lsb"
```

To get the css requires getting the contents of the second style tag and doing some text parsing, matching it to the desired css class:

```
read_html(url) %>% 
  html_elements('style') %>%
  pluck(2) %>%
  html_text() %>%
  strsplit('}') %>%
  getElement(1) %>%
  {.[nchar(.) > 1]} %>%
  paste0('}') %>%
  {grep(paste0('\\.', css_class, '\\{'), ., value = TRUE)} %>%
  {gsub(';', ';\n', .)} %>%
  cat()
#> .lsb{background:url(/images/nav_logo229.png) 0 -261px repeat-x;
#> color:#000;
#> border:none;
#> cursor:pointer;
#> height:30px;
#> margin:0;
#> outline:0;
#> font:15px arial,sans-serif;
#> vertical-align:top}
```

<sup>Created on 2023-12-12 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: I found a GitHub package that helps with the text parsing.  Answer is below.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to @Allan Cameron's answer, I found a package on [GitHub](https://github.com/coolbutuseless/cssparser) called `cssparser` that helps with some of the text parsing.

```r
library(rvest)
library(tidyverse)

# remotes::install_github('coolbutuseless/cssparser')
library(cssparser)

url <- r'(https://www.google.com)'

# function to format css
format_css <- function(text){
  text %>% 
    str_replace_all(
      pattern = ';(?!\\})', # add a new line after semi-colons unless they immediately precede a '}'
      replacement = ';\n\t'
    ) %>%
    str_replace_all(
      pattern = '\\{', # add a new line and a tab after '{'
      replacement = ' \\{\n\t'
    ) %>%
    str_replace_all(
      pattern = '\\}', # add a new line before and after a '}'
      replacement = '\n\\}\n'
    )
}

# parse css into a list
css_properties <-
  read_html(url) %>% 
    html_elements('style') %>% 
    html_text() %>% 
    format_css() %>% # otherwise css parser fails
    map(read_css) # from cssparser package
  
# format it as readable json
css_properties %>% 
  jsonlite::toJSON() %>% 
  jsonlite::prettify()
#> [
#>     {
#>         "#gbar": {
#>             "font-size": [
#>                 "13px"
#>             ],
#>             "padding-top": [
#>                 "1px"
#>             ]
#>         },
#>         "#guser": {
#>             "font-size": [
#>                 "13px"
#>             ],
#>             "padding-top": [
#>                 "1px"
#>             ]
#>         },
#>         "#gbar.1": {
#>             "height": [
#>                 "22px"
#>             ]
#>         },
#>         "#guser.1": {
#>             "padding-bottom": [
#>                 "7px"
#>             ],
#>             "text-align": [
#>                 "right"
#>             ]
#>         },
#>         ".gbh": {
#>             "border-top": [
#>                 "1px solid #c9d7f1"
#>             ],
#>             "font-size": [
#>                 "1px"
#>             ]
#>         },
#>         ".gbd": {
#>             "border-top": [
#>                 "1px solid #c9d7f1"
#>             ],
#>             "font-size": [
#>                 "1px"
#>             ]
#>         },
#>         ".gbh.1": {
#>             "height": [
#>                 "0"
#>             ],
#>             "position": [
#>                 "absolute"
#>             ],
#>             "top": [
#>                 "24px"
#>             ],
#>             "width": [
#>                 "100%"
#>             ]
#>         },
#>         "@media all": {
#>             ".gb1": {
#>                 "height": [
#>                     "22px"
#>                 ],
#>                 "margin-right": [
#>                     ".5em"
#>                 ],
#>                 "vertical-align": [
#>                     "top"
#>                 ]
#>             },
#>             "#gbar": {
#>                 "float": [
#>                     "left"
#>                 ]
#>             }
#>         },
#>         "a.gb1": {
#>             "text-decoration": [
#>                 "underline"
#>             ]
#>         },
#>         "a.gb4": {
#>             "text-decoration": [
#>                 "underline"
#>             ]
#>         },
#>         "a.gb1.1": {
#>             "color": [
#>                 "#00c"
#>             ]
#>         },
#>         "a.gb4.1": {
#>             "color": [
#>                 "#00c"
#>             ]
#>         },
#>         ".gbi .gb4": {
#>             "color": [
#>                 "#dd8e27"
#>             ]
#>         },
#>         ".gbf .gb4": {
#>             "color": [
#>                 "#900"
#>             ]
#>         }
#>     },
#>     {
#>         "body": {
#>             "font-family": [
#>                 "arial,sans-serif"
#>             ]
#>         },
#>         "td": {
#>             "font-family": [
#>                 "arial,sans-serif"
#>             ]
#>         },
#>         "a": {
#>             "font-family": [
#>                 "arial,sans-serif"
#>             ]
#>         },
#>         "p": {
#>             "font-family": [
#>                 "arial,sans-serif"
#>             ]
#>         },
#>         ".h": {
#>             "font-family": [
#>                 "arial,sans-serif"
#>             ]
#>         },
#>         "body.1": {
#>             "margin": [
#>                 "0"
#>             ],
#>             "overflow-y": [
#>                 "scroll"
#>             ]
#>         },
#>         "#gog": {
#>             "padding": [
#>                 "3px 8px 0"
#>             ]
#>         },
#>         "td.1": {
#>             "line-height": [
#>                 ".8em"
#>             ]
#>         },
#>         ".gac_m td": {
#>             "line-height": [
#>                 "17px"
#>             ]
#>         },
#>         "form": {
#>             "margin-bottom": [
#>                 "20px"
#>             ]
#>         },
#>         ".h.1": {
#>             "color": [
#>                 "#1967d2"
#>             ]
#>         },
#>         "em": {
#>             "font-weight": [
#>                 "bold"
#>             ],
#>             "font-style": [
#>                 "normal"
#>             ]
#>         },
#>         ".lst": {
#>             "height": [
#>                 "25px"
#>             ],
#>             "width": [
#>                 "496px"
#>             ]
#>         },
#>         ".gsfi": {
#>             "font": [
#>                 "18px arial,sans-serif"
#>             ]
#>         },
#>         ".lst.1": {
#>             "font": [
#>                 "18px arial,sans-serif"
#>             ]
#>         },
#>         ".gsfs": {
#>             "font": [
#>                 "17px arial,sans-serif"
#>             ]
#>         },
#>         ".ds": {
#>             "display": [
#>                 "inline-box"
#>             ],
#>             "display.1": [
#>                 "inline-block"
#>             ],
#>             "margin": [
#>                 "3px 0 4px"
#>             ],
#>             "margin-left": [
#>                 "4px"
#>             ]
#>         },
#>         "input": {
#>             "font-family": [
#>                 "inherit"
#>             ]
#>         },
#>         "body.2": {
#>             "background": [
#>                 "#fff"
#>             ],
#>             "color": [
#>                 "#000"
#>             ]
#>         },
#>         "a.1": {
#>             "color": [
#>                 "#681da8"
#>             ],
#>             "text-decoration": [
#>                 "none"
#>             ]
#>         },
#>         "a:hover": {
#>             "text-decoration": [
#>                 "underline"
#>             ]
#>         },
#>         "a:active": {
#>             "text-decoration": [
#>                 "underline"
#>             ]
#>         },
#>         ".fl a": {
#>             "color": [
#>                 "#1967d2"
#>             ]
#>         },
#>         "a:visited": {
#>             "color": [
#>                 "#681da8"
#>             ]
#>         },
#>         ".sblc": {
#>             "padding-top": [
#>                 "5px"
#>             ]
#>         },
#>         ".sblc a": {
#>             "display": [
#>                 "block"
#>             ],
#>             "margin": [
#>                 "2px 0"
#>             ],
#>             "margin-left": [
#>                 "13px"
#>             ],
#>             "font-size": [
#>                 "11px"
#>             ]
#>         },
#>         ".lsbb": {
#>             "background": [
#>                 "#f8f9fa"
#>             ],
#>             "border": [
#>                 "solid 1px"
#>             ],
#>             "border-color": [
#>                 "#dadce0 #70757a #70757a #dadce0"
#>             ],
#>             "height": [
#>                 "30px"
#>             ]
#>         },
#>         ".lsbb.1": {
#>             "display": [
#>                 "block"
#>             ]
#>         },
#>         "#WqQANb a": {
#>             "display": [
#>                 "inline-block"
#>             ],
#>             "margin": [
#>                 "0 12px"
#>             ]
#>         },
#>         ".lsb": {
#>             "background": [
#>                 "url(/images/nav_logo229.png) 0 -261px repeat-x"
#>             ],
#>             "color": [
#>                 "#000"
#>             ],
#>             "border": [
#>                 "none"
#>             ],
#>             "cursor": [
#>                 "pointer"
#>             ],
#>             "height": [
#>                 "30px"
#>             ],
#>             "margin": [
#>                 "0"
#>             ],
#>             "outline": [
#>                 "0"
#>             ],
#>             "font": [
#>                 "15px arial,sans-serif"
#>             ],
#>             "vertical-align": [
#>                 "top"
#>             ]
#>         },
#>         ".lsb:active": {
#>             "background": [
#>                 "#dadce0"
#>             ]
#>         },
#>         ".lst:focus": {
#>             "outline": [
#>                 "none"
#>             ]
#>         }
#>     }
#> ]
#>
```

<sup>Created on 2023-12-12 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>